# Magento 2: Review step after Payment with Place Order button

Tags: magento2

I have added custom **Review** step **after Payment**.

How to **move Place Order button** to last added **custom step**? Because every payment method has own button.

I have idea: in last custom step (review) call click on button in Payment step. But this idea is not good.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using css !!! Yes using css.

1. Make #checkout-step-payment position as relative.

   '#checkout-step-payment{position:relative;}'
2. Add below css in .actions-toolbar under payment method.

   .payment-method._active .payment-method-content > div.actions-toolbar{
       bottom: -40px;
       margin-left: -15px;
       position: absolute;
       width: 100%;
   }

**Note: Change bottom value as per your requirement.**